# Accessing/writing to Chrome app localStorage

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm writing a packaged app for Chrome. Is there an advantage to using the background page - instead of the app's main HTML page - to read/write the localStorage values?

Currently users seem to be losing data in ways I cannot duplicate. Right now the app reads and writes localStorage in the main HTML page's JavaScript. Would changing the app to use the background page's JavaScript fix this?

Comment: Could your users by chance be hitting a size limit of the localStorage for the related domain? As to your question, it doesn't matter much as long as you maintain security and do not run out of storage. One downside is that if you use a background page for localStorage, you won't be able to access its data without an extension.

Comment: @AlexanderPavlov the app is using Chrome's unlimitedStorage permission (http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/manifest.html#permissions), but now that I've taken a closer look at that page, it seems that it may not even apply to localStorage... perhaps I should be using indexedDB instead. Crap.

Comment: Indeed, unlimitedStorage does not apply to localStorage, and the [bug has been labeled WontFix](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=58985).  You should use [IndexedDB](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/IndexedDB) and/or [FileSystem storage](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/filesystem/), depending on the type of data you're storing. I made the exact same unfortunate discovery when writing my own app.

Answer (score 0):

LocalStorage is limited to 5 megabytes, regardless of set permissions.

When users checks the "Delete cookies and other website and plugin data" on chrome://settings/clearBrowserData then I believe both site specific and extension localstorage files are deleted. Maybe this is how your users are "losing" data.

Using the background page to read/write to localstorage **prevents** corruption of your data from other extensions, which can happen for site domain localstorage files as only your background page can access the file.
While other extensions indeed can call your background page, they still have to use your save/load functions to access your extension localstorage file.

Answer (score 0):

The problem might be with the context of the localStorage container.  When run from the background script you are saving the the localStorage of your extension.  When run from a content script you are saving to a localStorage are for that specific website.  localStorage.setItem( 'xx', 'yyy' ) that is written by a content script on a google.com page can't be read by localStore.getItem( 'xx' ) call from a content script on yahoo.com