# Embedding client ID in Chrome Extension for Server on Google App Engine

Tags: google-app-engine, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to find out as to what is the most appropriate way through which I can embed a client ID with my Google Chrome Extension? My intended purpose is that the end user can add my extension either through my website or through chrome store but he needs to provide an email address before doing that. Which could be appropriate in terms of achieving the functionality.

I studied about chrome extension on internet and one of the approach that I am thinking is that the end user can add the extension and whenever I receive the first request from user, I can generate an unique ID and embed it in to client's extension. Is it possible to modify the manifest file in order to do that and in case if I am doing this also I have no option to get the email address from the end-user. One of the approach can be also that I could do all the stuff at server side when the end user comes to add extension through my site, but how it is possible with GAE as GAE doesn't allow us to modify the contents of the file.

My application will be deployed on Google App Engine.

Also, to add is there a way through which I can modify the details of the client ID, in case if I need to do it in future?

Please advise.

Thanks.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by GAE does not allow you to modify the contents of the file. Sure, you can't modify files saved on the local filesystem  but nothing stops you creating a file "On the fly" and serving it to the user.

Comment: But how can I create a file if my extension is being added on chrome store. There I think it won't allow us to do something like this.

Comment: ah, ok, that's not GAE then, that's just the chrome app store preventing those changes. I believe you can use localstorage to store stuff on the clients PC, rather then embedding it in the manifest. This might be relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10194969/accessing-writing-to-chrome-app-localstorage

Comment: But contents to local storage will be lost if the client deletes all his history. And I want an ID that should always come with the request and that should be permanent so that I could identify a particular extension. Is there a way I can do this or else whenever the history is deleted, I need to generate a new key?

Comment: Are you aware that Chrome no longer allow hosting extensions in any place other than the Chrome Store?

Comment: yes, I am aware about the fact so on the fly option I think is no longer valid. So the option that stays is that I need to manage the key once the extension is added. How can I have the permanent storage for that key as I want that key to be one per extension? Any solution for these ?